# Is there any method you can use to check which parent your child was opened in?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue because I have a component that is used as a child component in two places, and I want to create a back button that sends the user back to the correct route.
I can do it with the individual parents:

```
<button open ref="backBtn" :back="`/parent1/${this.$route.params.id}/home`" />
<button open ref="backBtn" :back="`/parent2/${this.$route.params.id}/home`" />
```

But what I really want is a single button with a method that says:
Okay, you came from parent 1? Then use :back="`/parent1/${this.$route.params.id}/home`"
else, use :back="`/parent2/${this.$route.params.id}/home`"

Can it be done?

Comment: You could just provide the back uri as a prop. Just like IRL the parent tells the child what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `this.$router.back()` or `$router.back()`, it will go back from where it comes from.

If it doesn't work for you, you can use in your child the `this.$parent` to get information from your parent, even if it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT recommended:**

1. `router.go(-1)`
2. `router.back()` they work at the same way

**it's better** [to pass navigation settings for each back button](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location)

```
const username = 'username'
...
<router-link :to="{
   router.push({ name: 'user', params: { username } })
}" />
```